# ¿Solucion para cuando ejecuto comando de reac-native?

Tags: javascript, android-studio, react-native, genymotion

**Al colocar el comando "react-native run-android con el simulador de telefonos con Genymotion no me ejecuta, eh configurado las variables de entorno del JDK varias veces  y aun no logro avanzar.**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un problema en la configuración de la variable de entorno `JAVA_HOME` que esta apuntando al parecer al directorio JRE cuando debería apuntar al JDK, por ejemplo en mi caso es:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151
```

esta ruta es donde se encuentra: "tools.jar"